# Выбор значения элемента select, через jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, html-select

Как получить значение выбранного элемента я знаю.
Проблема с тем, каким событием отловить выбор элемента.
Если использовать `click()`, то выбирается первый элемент. Если использовать `change()`, то наоборот, первый элемент никак не выбрать.
Есть ли какие-нибудь другие варианты?

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```js
$("select").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 0) return false;
    
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="0">--Вы берите элемент--</option>
    <option value="1">Первый</option>
    <option value="2">Второй</option>
</select>
```

<sub>http://jsfiddle.net/Y5LsD/2/</sub>

Comment: Да, этот вариант я знаю. =)
Но думал, может есть более цивилизованный)

Comment: кстати, а как вы себе представляете более цивилизованный?

Answer (score 1):

Если пользователь выбирает тот же элемент в списке, который был выбран, то события change не происходит, так как ничего не изменилось. 
Чтобы всегда реагировать на выбор элемента, можно использовать следующее:

```
$('select option:selected').click(function(){
  var value = $(this).val() || $(this).text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: click не всегда сработает, в смысле можно клавиатурой выбрать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select').on({
 'click': function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
 },
 'keyup': function(){
   if(event.keyCode==13)
    console.log($(this).val());
 },
}, 'option')
```